# Meaning of # character in front of js_of_ocaml dom types

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

What is the meaning of the '#' in the following signature?

```
val insertBefore : #node Js.t -> #node Js.t -> #node Js.t Js.opt -> unit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `#-types` section of the OCaml reference manual (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/types.html).

A function type `#node -> t` takes an object of class `node` or its subclass and returns `t`.

For example,

```
class c = object method x = 1 end

let g : #c -> int = fun o -> o#x
```

Function `g` can take an object of class `c` or its subclass. `#c` is an abbreviation of `< x : int; ..>` therefore,

```
let h = (g : < x : int; ..> -> int)
```

is type-checked.